# Контроль версий в локальной сети

Tags: git

Имеется ПК с Win у которого есть доступ к расшаренной папке сервера http, где я веду поддержку, добавляю новый функционал и т.д, в общем постоянно "пилю" сайт, которым в этот же момент времени пользуются юзеры. Это не всегда удобно т.к.:
1. в процессе работы периодически у пользователей отключается какой-либо функционал;
2. имеется гора папок с версиями проекта;
3. неудобный откат к предыдущей версии в случае каких-либо ошибок.
Поставил локально Apache, PHP и т.д. и не могу понять(порядок) как настроить Git так, чтобы после проведения каких-либо работ и тестирования локально я сохранял бы эти изменения в расшаренной папке с "боевым" проектом?

PS: Интернета в корпоративной сети нет:)

Comment: @Bald Следующим этапом, если понадобится

Comment: @Bald выкладывание на сервер делается руками или Git-ом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В расшаренной папке web-севера создаете git-репозиторий
2. Клонируете его себе локально по файловому протоколу
3. Заливаете локально историю изменений из своих копий, если нужно
4. На сервере выполняете настройку `git config --local receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead` Это позволит обновлять локальную копию сервера автоматически, каждый раз как вы делаете `git push`
5. Работаете в своей локальной копии как обычно в git
6. Проверенные изменение push'ите на сервер.